# Direction of stack higher memory address to lower memory address

Tags: memory, stack, allocation

Direction of stack (higher memory address to lower memory address or from lower memory address to higher memory address) is dependent on machine architecture 
Example Intel  : higher memory address to lower memory address
SPARC : lower memory address to higher memory address

Is there any way by which we can change the direction of stack memory allocation using code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, management of the stack is performed by the compiler (assuming we're talking about something like C or C++ here).  However, the ISA may offer assistance, for instance `push` and `pop` instructions on x86.

There is no way to do this from C or C++, unless your compiler offers a non-portable language extension or a command-line option to control this (I can't see why it would, because changing this would make your program/library incompatible with all other programs/libraries!)

Comment: I was looking for same. Changing it through C code. And was also referring to stack created for function argument , local variables ..

Comment: @NoName: Yes, that is the stack that I am referring to as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is used on machine-instruction level. You cannot change processing unit behavior with code. The only thing one can do is to create program emulation level.

Answer (score 0):

Some processors include explicit circuitry which pushes things onto a stack and pops them in various circumstances.  Other processors do not include any such circuitry for a 'big' stack, but just provide a limited number of hardware registers or circuits that are used to store things like return addresses, and possibly a means by which software can copy the addresses stored in those registers or circuits to other parts of memory.

On processors whose hardware doesn't explicitly manipulate a stack in memory, one could use whatever pattern one wanted if one had control over all the code the processor would execute.  Generally, however, there will be a pattern that the processor manufacturer recommends for implementing a stack, and code generated by compilers or by other people will most likely expect to use a stack implemented in that fashion.